# Apache Tomcat 9 - HTTP Status 404 on browser

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, web.xml

I'm trying to create a simple web service, but I'm getting 404 when I try to go to the URL.
Here's the web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>Test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here's pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <artifactId>1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here's the basic rest class:

```
package Test;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

/**
 * Created by * on 4.02.2017.
 */


@Path("/api")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/test")
    public String getSmth(String request) {
        return "Testing";
    }
}
```

And when I go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/Test/rest/api/get/test
```

I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17
```

When I go to the Tomcat app manager I can see my app running there. Am I doing something really wrong or missing something?

Thanks,
Eerik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you are using glassfish server and not tomcat. In the IDE you are using try to use glassfish server instead of tomcat with the same code.